# jquery ajax call returns error on successful call to a servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

I have a servlet that adds a user to a file on the server side.
I invoke it with a jqueries ajax call.
I can see on the server that the method is being called correctly and my user is added, but the error callback is being invoked on the jquery call. All the status text says is error.
Using firebug the response seems to be empty. Why can I not get a success jquery callback?

```
//Servlet Code
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    String responseStr = "";
    if(action.equals("addUser")) 
    {  
      responseStr = addUser(request);       
    }
    System.out.println("Reponse:" + responseStr);  
    response.setContentType("application/json"); 
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8"); 
    response.getWriter().println(responseStr);
}

private String addUser(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
{
    Storage s;

    s = Storage.load();
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String imageUrl = request.getParameter("imageUrl");
    User u = new User();
    u.setName(name);
    u.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
    s.addUser(u);
    s.save();
    return "success";
}
```

.

```
//javascript code
function addUser() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var imageUrl = $('#imageUrl').val();
    var url = "http://ws06525:8080/QCHounds/QCHoundServlet?action=addUser&name=${name}&imageUrl=${imageUrl}";
    url = url.replace("${name}", name);
    url = url.replace("${imageUrl}", imageUrl);
    $('#result').html(url);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function( data ) {
         $('#result').html(data);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
      {
           alert("error: " + textStatus); 
           alert("error: " + errorThrown);
      }
    });


}
```

Comment: How is the response successful if FireBug shows the response to be empty?

Comment: What I mean is that the server side functionality successfuly executes and adds my user, but the reponse is indeed empty, I can't understand why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaargh! Feel like an idiot. It's a cross site scripting issue. 
I was testing the call to the server from the html file on disk so my browser address was

file://projects/myproject/content/Users.html   <<< Fail

instead of:

http://myboxname:8080/appname/Users.html  <<< Works

The actual code is fine...

Answer (score 1):

use this for learn what is the problem, it will be better for get solution i think

```
error: function(e){
    alert(JSON.stringify(e))
}
```

Comment: still get the error. Here it is: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: i guess its about your contentType or dataType of ajax call. Can you share your ajax call code?

Comment: You mean the actual ajax call? It is up in the question, just scroll a bit down in the code.

Comment: This answer did not help me solve the issue, but is very good advice. I did not know you could do that. +1

Answer (score 0):

For one thing the string `"success"` isn't valid json. If your ajax query is expecting json, that would fail it.

What if you returned `"{ \"success\": true }"` ?

EDIT

It looks like from your ajax call that the response shouldn't be json, why is your return content type json?

If it is true that firebug shows no response, your problem must be in the java code that writes the response.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't make a difference